# click on a link using jQuery on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link with a script in that opens a view of products. I don't have access to the html, and I need to have this view open on default. Until the behavior is fixed the correct way, which will take long time unfortunaly, I want to automatically make the link click on pageload.

I tried with the script below first - but since the link itself triggers a pageload, this obviously just keeps firing over and over again.

So how do I do this with jquery or vaniall JS, is this even possible?

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action')[0].click();
});
```

My link:

```
<a href="javascript://" name="_ec_rpd1" id="_ec_rpd1" class="action" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">Toon alle</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action:first').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: As i stated in my question - the link itself triggers a pageload so this creates a page load loop.

Answer (score 0):

to manually trigger an event u need to use `trigger()` ,`click` is to only assign a handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('a.action').click(function(){
   ... handler code
});

  $('a.action').trigger("click");

});
```

Comment: `$('.action')[0]` will return you underlying DOM element and DOM elements doesn't have jQuery methods

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me why you add [0], if you need to add it for first element then use following code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action:first').trigger("click");
});
```

otherwise you can directly use these :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.action').trigger("click");
});
```

Change your link tag with following :-

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" name="_ec_rpd1" id="_ec_rpd1" class="action" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">Toon alle</a>
```

Comment: As i stated in my question - the link itself triggers a page load so this creates a page load loop. The [0] i added just because it was in the example I found and tried, understand it isn't necessary now, thanks.

Comment: got your solution or still finding?

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` method triggers the click event.

Syntax :

*Trigger the click event for the selected elements:*

```
$(selector).click();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_click_trigger))

**In your case :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.action:first').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript://" name="_ec_rpd1" id="_ec_rpd1" class="action" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">Toon alle</a>
```

**Edit :**
If you don't want to trigger in a specific page. do like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!location.href.indexOf("someurl") > -1)
        $('.action:first').click();
});
```

Comment: As i stated in my question - the link itself triggers a pageload so this creates a page load loop.

Comment: you can check the condition with `location.href` and trigger the `click`

Comment: well the url wont change - so whats the condition i should use?

Comment: append a query string, in you `anchor` link so that you can identify from the url  and  by the way what does this function `UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click')` do?